# Paging with image and labels swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol, scroll-paging

I'm currently working on a project to show some information about beverages. I've made my view in my storyboard but I'm searching for an answer to implement my view.

I'm working in swift.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F31Wg.jpg

I've been looking for some code to implement this scrollbar with paging. If it's possible to make a paging scroll view with 3 labels and 1 picture. I would implement those 4 things for every page.

Is there someone with a good tutorial or answer? The only tutorials I've got were for showing only images...

Answer (score -1):

You could use a collection view and set its scroll direction to horizontal and then rig up each cell with the the image and labels. 
And then since UICollectionView is a subclass of scrollView you can calculate is contentOffset and divide it with the width of each cell to calculate which cell is shown to update your page indicator.

Here's a neat [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/) to get you started with UICollectionView's